# Why is my library not being recognized after importing my project?

Tags: intellij-idea, libraries

I'm using the JDBC library in my IntelliJ project (mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar)

I put it into a folder named lib and used right click > Add as Library to add it as a library. It worked fine.

Later, I zipped the project and moved it to another computer. After unzipping it and importing it in IntelliJ, it gave me the error `SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql`, which means that it couldn't find the library.

I looked through the file explorer in IntelliJ and it showed both the jar and XML file, and the XML file was pointing to the right location (`jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar`).

I added the jar file as a library again and now it works. But how can I make it work without having to readd it each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was overwriting the IntelliJ Module Library `(.iml)` file.

When you import a project to the same folder, IntelliJ asks you whether you want to overwrite or reuse the IML file. Since Overwrite was the default option, I selected it, but that caused it to forget what libraries it was using.

By choosing Reuse instead, it works perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Gradle (or Maven) for building and dependency management. IDEA should import a Gradle (or Maven) project just fine.